# Which is the best way to store data in windows phone?

Tags: database, windows-phone-7

When my app loads first, it will make an api call and stores the list of objects (around 200 objects)which are received as response(Each object will have around 10 variables),I have to store it in a database and from then onwards, i will get the list from the database only,

In android i stored the data in SQlite, and in ios data are stored in it's db
Where can i store my data in windows phone?? in isolated Storage?? or in sqlite?? or in local database??
What are the difference between isolated storage, sqlite and local database??
It should increase the performance.

Comment: Well i could suggest IsolatedStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i just answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451686/which-is-the-best-database-for-windows-phone/19460221#19460221), you should first decide, which operations you're going to perform at most.

As for 200 objects, i think, storing to the simplest json would be enough (or even binary, it would be even faster, but json is readable).