# Which is the best database for windows phone

Tags: database, windows-phone-7

I have around 10 tabs, each tab would be having all the four operations of CRUD(Create,Read,Update,Delete).
In all the tab while getting the list from server, I have planned to save them in the Database(as I am building a native app).
I read about *isolated storage(files and also Local Database)* and *SQLite*.
Regarding ***SQLite***, as it is a third party database,I think it will affect the performance.

So what shall I use??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard some recommendations about Sterling DB, but i didn't make a crash-tests for DB yet.

I guess, you should decide more exact, what would be the most often operations. Take a look at performance tests here:

http://www.jayway.com/2010/11/17/performance-of-sterling-database-for-windows-phone-7/

http://www.maxpaulousky.com/blog/archive/2011/07/27/windows-phone-mango-db-engines-performance-testing.aspx

Comment: The first link states that Sterling DB's performance is terrible.

Comment: Yep, but it depends on usage. Say, if you have an application with pre-built database, and user is reading it quite often - than its the way for Sterling. Though, i agree with you: performance is horrible in storing new data.